# libupnp UpnpInit throw 117 error

Tags: android, java-native-interface, upnp

Hi maybe my question is very hard to answer, need you have some experience in libupnp.so development.
   I'm working on a project based on **libupnp**, but when i start, this issue block me. From the libupnp API, i need to invoke the method **UpnpInit** to initialize the upnp service, but it throw  117 error which represent the allocate resource failure. I don't know where error. In addition, my app is a Android project that call C layer with the JNI, but this procedure has been run through.. So if you have some relevant experience, it's very appreciate your help..

Answer (score 0):

Now, i have found the root cause, it's very stupid, you should add INTERNET permission for you Android application.